# html how to keep table columns for table in table

Tags: html, css

I wish to get table that looks like this:
[image]

Blue element is auto generated table in main table.

Problem is that i don't now how to keep columns. Best i can do is:

[image]

My html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        table, th, td {
          border: 1px solid black;
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th, td {
          padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <th>
                Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Zm
            </th>
            <th>
                Service
            </th>
            <th>
                Pozition
            </th>
            <th >
                Operation
            </th>
            <th >
                Material Typ
            </th>
            <th >
                Batch and weight
            </th>
            <th>
                Output length
            </th>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    2021-03-28
                </td>
                <td>
                    I
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" style="width: 90px;"> <br>
                    <input type="text" style="width: 90px;">
                </td>
                <td>
                    1
                </td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <table>
                        
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Izol
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                LS4201R
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text"> <br>
                                <input type="text"> <br>
                                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text"><br>
                                <input type="text"><br>
                                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                EkWZ
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                LE0592
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text"><br>
                                <input type="text"><br>
                                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    2530
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    
                </td>
                <td>
                    
                </td>
                <td>
                    
                </td>
                <td>
                    2
                </td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            
                            <td>
                                Izol
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                LS4201R
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text"> <br>
                                <input type="text"> <br>
                                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text"><br>
                                <input type="text"><br>
                                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                EkWZ
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                LE0592
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text"><br>
                                <input type="text"><br>
                                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    3020
                </td>
            </tr>
            


        </tbody>




    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Styling is from another answer on the portal, but i don't now how remove space between main table and nested.

Can some one help me whit styling? I'm learning python and don't now JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to remove the padding in the columns that has a sub table and have some fixed width on the columns.

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.table-inner td {
    padding: 0;
}

.table-inner {
    border: none;
}

.table-inner tr:first-child td {
    border-top: none;
}

.table-inner tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.table-inner td:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

.table-inner td:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

.table-responsive {
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.no-border {
    border: none;
}

.p-0 {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="min-width: 120px; width: 120px">Date</th>
                <th style="min-width: 80px;width: 80px">Zm</th>
                <th style="min-width: 90px;width: 90px">Service</th>
                <th style="min-width: 80px;width: 80px">Pozition</th>
                <th style="min-width: 150px;width: 150px">Operation</th>
                <th style="min-width: 150px;width: 150px">Material Typ</th>
                <th style="min-width: 170px; width: 170px">Batch and weight</th>
                <th style="width: auto">Output length</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>2021-03-28</td>
                <td>I</td>
                <td class="p-0">
                    <input type="text" style="width: 90px;"><br />
                    <input type="text" style="width: 90px;">
                </td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td colspan="3" class="p-0">
                    <table class="table-inner">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="min-width: 160px;width: 160px">Izol</td>
                                <td style="min-width: 160px;width: 160px">LS4201R</td>
                                <td style="min-width: 170px;width: 170px">
                                    <input type="text"><br />
                                    <input type="text"><br />
                                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text"><br />
                                    <input type="text"><br />
                                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>EkWZ</td>
                                <td>LE0592</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text"><br />
                                    <input type="text"><br />
                                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>2530</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td colspan="3" class="p-0">
                    <table class="table-inner">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="min-width: 160px;width: 160px">Izol</td>
                                <td style="min-width: 160px;width: 160px">LS4201R</td>
                                <td style="min-width: 170px;width: 170px">
                                    <input type="text"><br />
                                    <input type="text"><br />
                                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text"><br />
                                    <input type="text"><br />
                                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>EkWZ</td>
                                <td>LE0592</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text"><br />
                                    <input type="text"><br />
                                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>3020</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```